# Can I make Visual Studio only build each project in a solution once?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

After increasing the verbosity of the Output window in Visual Studio, I've noticed that when building my solution, every time a project is built it rebuilds all other projects that that project references in the solution. This seems like an exponential waste of time.  Can I make it just build each once?

I am using VS 2017.4 and my solution is all C# projects targeting .NET 4.6

Comment: Are you saying that if projects are building more than once with a single "Build Solution" operation?  Can you post the output from VS?

Comment: Have you use the option `Rebuild Solution` or `Rebuild` every time when you build you solution/project? If yes, please use `Build Solution` or `Build` instead. `Build solution`/ `Build` will perform an incremental build. If you have not any modification on the references projects, VS would not build those references projects. And `Rebuild solution`/`Rebuild` will clean and then build the solution from scratch, ignoring anything it’s done before. If I understand you incorrect, please give me some more detailed info.

Comment: Are you sure it *rebuilds* them? As in, calls the actual Clean/Build targets? (and not just targets for resolving output paths etc, which are needed for figuring out where to copy outputs from dependent projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSBuild always needs to check to make sure that referenced projects are still up to date.  This means that it will "touch" every project that your target project depends on, but that doesn't mean it will actually "compile" each of them.  You can tell the difference by the final output:

`========== Build: x succeeded, 0 failed, y up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

If you only touched one project x should 1 and y would be the total number of other projects that the one project depends on.